# Tools and methodologies to keep to DBs aligned

Tags: postgresql, schema, maintenance, postgresql-9.2

2 DBs having schemas that represent the same semantic objects.
The first one is production DB (Non-RDBMS, in-house implemented in-memory DB with shitload of RAM). Other is Postgres.

Once in a while the production DB is changed (schema upgrade).

Question: what is the best practice to keep DBs of different types aligned semantically?

Comment: Possible duplicate from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175451/how-do-you-version-your-database-schema

Comment: Keep in mind that your options are going to be severely limited if you're using a custom, in-house database.  Additionally, it's generally considered best practice for dev and prod to at least use the same systems.  Having dev be Postgres but prod be custom-memory.db is a little awkward.

Comment: We are quite satisfied using Liquibase for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep all SQL DDL in "patch" files in source control.

add a "schema_version" table to your database and track the latest patch file you are on.

write a script that runs new patches against your dbs.